# Convert whole row into a JSON string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I want to log deleted rows into a single column, by converting them into a JSON string.
How can I convert the whole row into JSON without specifying column names one by one?
For example result I want to convert the result of the following query into a JSON, without specifying each column name:

```
select * from table_1 limit 1
```

Comment: *How can I convert the whole row into JSON without specifying column names one by one?* Noway. None JSON creating function accepts `*` as column name parameter. You may query the columns names from INFORMATION_SCHEMA, build the statement and use dynamic SQL (or build columns names CSV list and copypaste it to your query).

Comment: You could also create a trigger on delete and store the information in another way, or even by constructing a JSON. Calling SELECT before DELETE may lead to issues if for any reason your DELETE fails.